# Ruby on Rails - Is it possible to show specific content on two views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any helper method in Ruby on Rails which allows me to show content from a rendered **_form.html.haml** so that the content will only show up if and only if the **view** in which I render the form will just show me a specific part of the **_form.html.haml**?

For better understanding let me show you an example: Let **a.html.haml**, **b.html.haml** be views.
Further let **_form.html.haml** be a form.

**a.html.haml** and **b.html.haml** got both the following content inside:

**=render 'form'**

All i want now is that **a** is just loading a specific part from the **form** which fits to **a** AND
**b** is just loading a specific part from the **form** which fits to **b**.

Comment: I assume they share some fields?

Comment: as japed said, unless they share fields, why not make two different partials?  showing your code would help...

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would set it up something like this, trying to find a balance between "do not repeat yourself" and comprehensibility.

Three partials:

```
_a_form.html.haml
_b_form.html.haml
_shared_form.html.haml
```

in _a_form.html.haml

```
<!-- some stuff that is unique to a_form -->
.content
  = render :partial => 'shared_form'
<!-- some more stuff that is unique to a_form -->
```

in _b_form.html.haml

```
<!-- some stuff that is unique to b_form -->
.content
  = render :partial => 'shared_form'
<!-- some more stuff that is unique to b_form -->
```

Comment: Seems sensible, and it you're using form_for you can pass the form object to the partial.